# Собственный ListItem для PreferenceFragment

Tags: android

Как можно использовать собственный ListItem для PreferenceFragment? xml-ка для ListItem создана, но я не могу найти, как её применить. В onCreateView подгружается собственный View с ListView.

```
public class MenuFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);    
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen screen,
        Preference pref) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_with_listview, null);
    return v;
}
}
```

Как я понимаю, собственных адаптеров создавать не надо?

---

#### Добавление:

Имеются ресурсы для настроек в виде:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/properties">
    <Preference android:title="@string/options" />
    <Preference android:title="@string/fs_access" />
 </PreferenceCategory>
 <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/output" >
    <Preference android:title="@string/output" />
 </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Я их загружаю в PreferenceFragment c помощью `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main);`
Только что обнаружил, что можно отдельно настроить каждый элемент списка, например:

```
 <Preference android:title="@string/output"
             android:layout="@layout/listitem/>
```

Так и нужно действовать в данной ситуации и дописывать эту строку для всех настроек или есть другой способ?

---

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно, что конкретно вы хотите сделать, PreferenceList со своими custom элементами? Если так, то см. пример [здесь](http://blog.isys-labs.com/creating-a-custom-listpreference/)

После обновлений: Если вы хотите для всех Preference использовать свой layout, то можете отнаследоваться от системного классса Preference. Посмотрите его исходники в исходниках android, там же есть и preference.xml - стандартный layout для Preference.

Comment: Свой listitem.xml я строю на основе этого preference.xml. У класса Preference есть метод setLayoutResource(int). Но как им воспользоваться из PreferenceFragment не понимаю(